# Users change codes directly on the production server

Tags: python, database, git, production-environment, production

I'm working on a project that has all its data written as python files(codes). Users with authentication could upload data through a web page, and this will directly add and change codes on the production server. This is causing trouble every time I want to git pull changes from the git repo to the production server since the codes added by users directly on production are untracked.
I wonder if anyone has some other ideas. I know this is ill-designed but this is what I got from the beginning, and implementing a database will require a lot of effort since all the current codes are designed for python files.I guess it's because the people who wrote this didn't know much about databases and it works only because there is relatively little data.

The only two solutions I could think of is

1. use a database instead of having all datas being codes
2. git add/commit/push all changes on the production server every time the user upload data

Details added:
There is a 'data' folder of python files, with each file storing the information of a book. For instance, latin_stories.py has a dictionary variable text, an integer variable section, a string variable language, etc. When users upload a csv file according to a certain format, a program will automatically add and change the python files in the data folder, directly on the production server.

Comment: What does "Datas being codes" mean? This DOES sound terribly designed. Perhaps share some examples of what users are able to update and why?

Comment: Is the python code getting updated automatically by a program based on the data that is uploaded by the users? Are the users programmers?

Comment: There is a 'data' folder of python files, with each file storing the information of a book. For instance, latin_stories.py has a dictionary variable text, an integer variable section, a string variable language, etc. When users upload a csv file according to a certain format, an algorithm will add and change the python files in the data folder, directly on the production server.

Comment: Yes, it is updated automatically. No, the users are not programmers.

Comment: From performance standpoint, storing stuff in .py files means all data has to be loaded into memory, which means you may run out of memory if the files get bigger, and this also means slower startup, so the database option will become a necessity in the future anyway.

Comment: It's better to start the implementation of the DB layer. I would start by adding a repository layer to the codebase. Create a Repository class that is responsible for reading, updating, deleting, etc stuff from your data folder. And use it where your other codes call data from your data folder. So, your other codes will be agnostic about your DB layer. After some point, you can add a new database, move old data to there and only change the repository layer connection with that. You need to create a boundary between the DB/persistence layer and others. Then you can easily switch db.

Comment: Thanks so much for the comments! These are all really helpful and I'll work on the database.